# VS Code CSS class folding keeps folding not properly

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, folding, code-folding

I know there are several shortcuts such as *( Ctrl+K > Ctrl+L )* etc. but I cannot solve/fix how from a couple of days my CSS sheet is folding.
Instead of havin' a closing brackets in the class name, there are some in some parameters of the class, and it's like that for kinda every class *(as in the picture)*.
Probably I've changed some parameters not on purpose cause was all well separated n clean while now VS Code decided to fold some class together apparently with no logic at least for me.

Any leads appreciated.
**Thank you**

[image]

Comment: 1) does this happen in smaller files? 2) does this happen in a way that is reproducible, or are the specific problematic lines different after a restart of VS Code? 3) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.